# Comparing two CSV files in python and output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two CSV files. I need to compare file1 with file2 and output any lines that are in file1 which are not in file2. Issue is when there is two lines with exact value in file1. Output should show the value that is not in file2 instead it is removing both values as duplicates. Is there any way to do this?

The code I am using now is

```py
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as t2:
            fileone = t1.readlines()
            filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('addressList.csv', 'w') as outFile:
         for line in fileone:
             if line not in filetwo:
                      outFile.write(line)
            sys.exit()
```

file1 :

`address, value`

2ce8e,200

2ce8e,200

fb0d7,350

fb0d7,225

fb0d7,250

fb0d7,361

fb0d7,175

fb0d7,450

file2 :

`address, value`

2ce8e,200

fb0d7,350

fb0d7,250

fb0d7,225

fb0d7,175

fb0d7,361

fb0d7,450

output should be

`address, value`

2ce8e,200

Comment: You can do this using the command line `diff` tool without any programming at all.

Comment: i need to save the out put in a csv format as another script is going to using the data

Comment: `diff` prints out the differing lines.  I'm just pointing out that it's usually better to use or adapt existing tools than to write new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python's `set` type. Each element in a `set` must be distinct so it automatically deduplicates its elements. The operations provided on `set` types make it very easy to compare elements. Look up Python's documentation and mathematical set theory for more information.

Example:

```py
fileone = set(t1.readlines())
filetwo = set(t2.readlines())

# get lines from fileone that are not in filetwo (set difference)
diff12 = fileone - filetwo

# get lines from filetwo that are not in fileone (set difference)
diff21 = filetwo - fileone

# get lines in common between fileone and filetwo (set intersection)
common = fileone & filetwo
```

It seems like you need to preserve ordering of the lines though, which `set` will not do on its own. You can still make use of sets to make this process faster, however.